# Spring’s cache in Alfresco

Tags: spring, caching, alfresco

I am trying to use the spring's cache in Alfresco, but when I start tomcat I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from class path resource [alfresco/module/PolmanProject-alfresco-repo/context/service-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 8; cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'.
```

I have the following module-context:

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'> 

<beans>
...
    <cache:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
        <property name="caches">
            <set>
                <bean
            class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean"
                    name="cacheService" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

If I remove  and the bean cacheManager, then, I don't get the exception.

What is wrong in my context?

Answer (score 1):

You should comment the line

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC '-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN' 'http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd'> -->
```

and replace the tag  with

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">
```

And that will solve your issue. However, it's neccesary take into account another details to use the cache. This post explains [how to use the cache step by step](http://howtobrothers.com/2017/09/14/how-to-use-springs-cache-in-alfresco/)

Comment: That fixes my issue. Thank you!